# Slow connection to SQL Server both locally and by client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connectivity

Yesterday I was experiencing extremely slow connectivity to the SQL Server with connections via management studio taking 5+ seconds where normally connecting to the server occurs within seconds. This issue both happened when connecting to the SQL Server on the actual server VM and then also from client pcs. Executing requests on their own seemed to be fine once connected, we just appeared to have issues connecting to the SQL Server it self.

CPU Utilisation had spikes but averaged around 75% with memory also around the 85 % mark suggesting resources were available for clients to connect.

Given that we are not experiencing the issues right now, is there any way I can troubleshoot what was causing it and if not and should we experience the issues again, is there anything I should look for in particular with Extended Events when troubleshooting?

Thanks

Comment: SQL authentication or Windows? If Windows Auth, your SQL Server may have been having trouble communicating with a domain controller to authenticate logins.

Comment: Hi @handy, thanks for your response. It was windows authentication. Is there a way I can prove the issue communicating to the domain controller?

Comment: Not likely after the fact, you might find something useful in the Windows event logs, maybe other applications reporting issues contacting the DC, but typically these issues have to be caught during the event. I've seen it previously where local DCs were offline and remote DCs were being used for auth. Everything worked fine, but the logins slowed considerably due to the extra time required for authentication.

Comment: Ok, if we have the same issue again, is there a way I can prove it is at that point in time, it's an issue communicating to the DC?

Comment: You need to get information on the login process. Start a profiler trace and capture RPC, SQL Statement & PreConnect - Starting/Completed (filter it to your login to avoid a flood of data) as a start. Look for areas where the bottlenecks are occurring. It could be DC comms, DNS etc. Try connecting via IP as well to see if that changes performance.

Comment: Also, you can try setting your connection timeout to 1 second (to force a failure since connecting takes ~5 seconds) and the error message should contain some information on where exactly the delay was.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to see performance in the past unless you have a monitoring system in place during the event in question.

Assuming you don't have a monitoring solution in place, you could be prepared in case this happens in future.

For instance, you could look at wait stats over a time period using my [wait stats capture script](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/troubleshooting/wait-stats-capture-script/).  The script shows what SQL Server actually waited on over a short period of time.  For instance, if you happened to run that script while the problem in your questions was occurring, it's possible the output might show thread starvation via the `THREADPOOL` wait.  Check Paul Randal's site for details about that [wait](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/threadpool/).